# Local Rankin-Selberg Zeta-function and Coates' p-adic L-Functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, convolution, p-adic

$\DeclareMathOperator\Kern{Kern}\DeclareMathOperator\diag{diag}$
Let $F$ be a non-archimedean local field, $\mathcal{O}$ its ring of integers, $\mathfrak{p}$ its maximal ideal and $\pi$ a uniformizer.

Moreover I fix an additive character $\psi \colon F \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$ (with $\mathcal{O} \subset \Kern(\psi)$, but $\pi^{-1}\mathcal{O} \not\subset \Kern(\psi)$) and a multiplicative character $\chi \colon F^{\times} \to \mathbb{C}^{\times}$.

Let further $G = \mathrm{GL}_n$ and $U = U_n$ be the subgroup of upper-triangular matrices with 1's on its diagonal.

Then $\psi$ induces a character of $U(F)$ and $\chi$ a character of $G(F)$ in a standard way. At last I need the matrices
$$
\pi^{t_n} = \diag(\pi^n,\pi^{n-1},\ldots,\pi) \in G(F),
$$
$w_0$ is the long Weyl-Element, which consists on $1$s on the antidiagonal and $0$s elsewhere, and
$$
h_{n+1} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & & & 1 \\
& \ddots & & \vdots \\
& & 1 & 1 \\
& & & 1
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathrm{GL}_{n+1}(F).
$$

I was tasked to consider (and compute) the (local) Rankin-Selberg Zeta function given as
$$
\int\limits_{U(F)\backslash G(F)} \mathcal{W}( \begin{pmatrix}
g & \\
& 1 
\end{pmatrix} h_{n+1} \begin{pmatrix}
w_0 \pi^{f \cdot t_n} & \\
& 1
\end{pmatrix})\cdot \mathcal{W}'(g\pi^{f \cdot t_n}) \cdot \chi(g) \cdot \|g\|^{s-1/2} dg,
$$
where $f \geq \max\{1, \mathfrak{c}(\chi)\}$ and $(\mathcal{W},\mathcal{W}')$ is a $(\psi, \psi^{-1})$-pair of (right)-Iwahori-invariant Whittaker functions on $\mathrm{GL}_{n+1} \times \mathrm{GL}_n$.

My professor told me that the appearance of $h_{n+1}$ as well as of the $w_n$ and $\pi^{t_n}$ is important, because of interpolation; Coates states in his paper ([https://math.hawaii.edu/~rharron/seminars/p-adic_L-functions/Coates%20[1991]%20Motivic%20p-adic%20L-functions.pdf](https://math.hawaii.edu/%7Erharron/seminars/p-adic_L-functions/Coates%20%5B1991%5D%20Motivic%20p-adic%20L-functions.pdf)) how such a motivic Zeta-function behaves and hence, by the conjectural correspondence between motives and aut.reps, one should also expect this on the automorphic site. More precisely my prof told me that:
a) By plugging in those matrices inside $\mathcal{W}$, one gets the 'right' expression on the automorphic side (as in the paper of Coates) and hence can interpolate a p-adic L-function.
b) The interpolation would not work without those matrices.

What one can see quickly is that if $h_{n+1}$ wouldn't appear, then the integral would be $0$ for $\chi$ ramified. Also, for $\chi$ ramified, the computation is smooth and the expression is (modulo correction factors) what Coates' paper says.

But I am struggling horribly with the computation when $\chi$ is non-ramified (then $\chi$ is actually absorbed by the norm, so it can be dropped). In my computation, I come to a point where the integral reduces to a finite sum and I don't manage to bring $\mathcal{W}$ to a 'pure form' of $\mathcal{W}(\pi^e w)$ where $e \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ and $w$ is some Weyl-Element (due to the $\psi$-left-twisting and right-Iwahori-invariance, every Iwahori-Whittaker function is determined by its values on $\pi^e w$). I feel that I am still missing some property. So my questions is if somebody could give me any hint on

1. why exactly those matrices are the 'right' thing to put inside $\mathcal{W}$,
2. relations with (local) Whittaker functions (except the obvious ones),
3. and maybe also explain if and why the expression is also right for the case when $\chi$ is unramified.

Comment: I think I understood now the point 3., and as it seems, I don't need 2. yet; I will come to it later. For now, I will have to accept 1. the way it is.

Comment: This is a hopelessly late comment on (1), in case you are still interested. The matrix h_n is important as it is an ‘open orbit representative’ of the spherical variety G/H, where G = GL(n)xGL(n+1) and H = GL(n), diagonally embedded.  More precisely, this means if B is a Borel in GL(n) x GL(n+1), then $B\cdot h_n\cdot H$ is Zariski open in G. This sort of thing appears to be essential for p-adic interpolation of, say, cohomology classes; for examples in this language see eg David Loeffler’s recent paper in the Iwasawa 2019 proceedings.

Comment: …If such a matrix is required to interpolate the cohomology, and hence construct measures/distributions, then it must also appear in the associated integrals. As to the $\pi_n^{t_n}$, another essential component of interpolation is the action of Hecke operators. In your case, the double coset operator (at Iwahori level) attached to $\pi^{t_n}$ is a natural analogue of the $U_p$ Hecke operator for modular forms.

Comment: Philosophically, you should be able to replace $h_n$ with *any* open orbit representative, and $\pi^{t_n}$ with *any* element of the torus that gives the correct Hecke operator. As you realised actually computing these integrals is often very difficult and there’s a game to play in choosing the matrices to make the computation nice. (Eg in my recent GL(3) preprint with Loeffler https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.04535.pdf , the matrix $u$ after Def 6.3 plays the role of $h_n$. The choice of $u$ looks unnatural but was madeto make the local zeta computation easier for ramified $\pi_p$).